# how to call a custom python script to maya (via deadline rendering toolkit)

Tags: python, maya

I have a maya job which is to be submitted in maya deadline rendering toolkit And I have a custom python script for analyzing maya file. I want to run the analyzing script first and then submit the job.

How to do this as maya deadline GUI doesn't have any feature to do so

Comment: "Is there any way to do this ?" Yes. Also: please have a look at the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: Sorry i am new  user I phrased the question in a wrong manner

Comment: What are you using? This maybe? [maya deadline rendering toolkit](https://docs.thinkboxsoftware.com/products/deadline/7.0/1_User%20Manual/manual/overview.html#jobs)

Comment: yes I am using the the same deadline by thinkbox

Comment: Do I have to put my analyze code in General Scripts or Job Scripts in section https://docs.thinkboxsoftware.com/products/deadline/8.0/1_User%20Manual/manual/monitor-scripts.html#general-scripts-ref-label

Comment: in the mel shelf button "send to adline" I was used to put my python script using : string $myList = python("import test; test.checkup()");